# Unable to connect webserver 'IIS Express'

Tags: c#, .net, iis, asp.net-core

I changed my launch setting to support remote IP hosting:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://192.168.1.69:55446/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "myapplication": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It works well in my system.

Ihen I download my project from TFS in another remote system and changed the ipaddress to support remote ip hosting and run the application in adminstrator mode. But still it showing "Unable to connect webserver 'IIS Express'"

```
 {
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://192.168.1.79:55446/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "eBMSForumApplication": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Mby check a port. If its no free can get error

Comment: I don't know exactly what's wrong in your situation, but another solution might be to use our free VS Extension called Conveyor -> https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a429dbb7-a982-4541-b401-934375c02c0f?redir=0 it allows connections to IIS Express from other machines/devices.

Comment: @raj, did you ever find out the cause of this? I have asked a similar question here today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56890385/create-binding-causes-unable-to-connect-to-web-server-iis-express.  Thanks.

Comment: for me it was port issue i changed the port issue in the  applicationUrl launch settings.json and it worked

Answer (score 16):

If you see something like this in the output console:

```
IIS Express starting...
iis express Failed to register URL "http://localhost:61367/" for site application "/". 
Error description: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by 
another process
```

The error is due to the port you are using.

Open a console and check out used port ranges with this command:

```
netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp
```

It will look like this:

[image]

Change the port number you wanna use, which is outside of those ranges.

Answer (score 5):

This problem is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/67990888/733760 and could be related to Hyper-v reserving a bunch of port ranges.

If that's the problem, the same answer applies (and worked for me).
Run as admin:

```
net stop winnat
net start winnat
```

Comment: Make sure to exit IIS Express in the command tray and then run the above command.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I unchecked "Enable SSL" in debug from project properties and ran the project. It made an iis pop up to appear which said the port is being used by chrome. So I closed all instances of chrome and switched again to "Enable SSL" and it fixed my issue.

Answer (score 2):

The same thing happened but I don't know the reason, I restarted IIs and VS which didn't work. Then I restarted the computer, it is all fixed.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had modified the project url in the debug mode, and after that it failed to run, I had to restart my Visual Studio in order to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this issue recently (along with some others: VS 2019 does not open web app project in chrome if chrome is already open) and found out that I was running VS in administrator mode.

I resolved this by running VS and Chrome in normal mode.

Answer (score 0):

my project version 2.2
[image]
my computer version 5.0 (cmd: dotnet --list-sdks)
[image]

I installed version 2.2 to my computer. I can run the application now.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all suggested solutions but for me the only solution is to go cert store delete my dev certificate (localhost) and solved.